# Using an arraylist combined with an array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

So I want to use an arraylist combined with an array, essentially a 2d array list but with the first level as an array list and the second level as an array.
I know that arraylists or arrays can be used as 2d alone, but my first set of data I don't know the size, whereas the second set I know the size to be 30

To give an example the array list should contain names something like

```
{"bob", "dave", "pete", "alan"}
```

and then for each name I want to attach an array of size 30, if I was using just arrays I imagine it'd be something like

```
String[][] array = new String[?][30]();
```

and then I'd add the names using something like

```
array[0] = "bob";
```

and then add data using

```
array[0][0] = 1;
```

but I want the first one to be an arraylist

Sorry if this isn't clear, feel free to ask for more explanation

Comment: *"but I want the first one to be an arraylist"*, your English doesn't make much sense as well as the code. Please rewrite.

Comment: Sounds more like a `Map<String, String[]>` than a `List<String[]>`...

Comment: Why dont you use `Map<String, List<String>>`

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible approaches.

1) If you don't care about the order of the items, you could use a `Map<String, String[]>`, with the names ("bob") as keys, and the arrays of length 30 as the values.

2) You could have two separate `ArrayList`s - one for the names, and one for the arrays. The downside of this is that you have to be careful to update them together.

```
List<String> names;
List<String[]> values;
```

3) You could create an Entry class that contains a name and a values array, then store these Entry objects in an `ArrayList`.

```
class Entry {
  String name;
  String[] values;   
  // etc
}

...

List<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<Entry>(); //etc
```